# Access to the path /Documents is denied

Tags: xamarin

I'm literally just trying to write a file to a android device - simple stuff.

But the device i'm using does not have "storage/emulated/0" so i've tried to get around that by saving a file to the documents folder.

Heres my method:

```
    public string WriteToFile(string fileContents, string fileName)
    {
        var documents = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments, WriteToFileFolderName);
        var filePath = documents + fileName;

        if (!Directory.Exists(documents))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(documents);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, fileContents);

        return filePath;
    }
```

But i get the error "/documents is denied".

Very frustrating

Comment: you can't just write to any arbitrary folder on a device - I suggest your read the docs first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/

Comment: okay i did. so i changed the docs var to this:   `var documents = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, WriteToFileFolderName);` . But its looking in a folder "storage/emulated/0". The device im using has a folder called sdcard and doesnt use the above folder . I tried doing a string . replace but i still get access denied